# File not found error message does not appear in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-3

I'm learning Code Igniter. Basically what I want to do is to show a *404* error message when users go to a URL that does not exist in `views` directory.

So I made a new file at `application/controllers/` called `Pages.php` which goes like this:

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
?>
```

Then I created a folder named `templates` at *views* directory which contains a `header.php` file and a `footer.php` file. And I created also a `pages`  folder under the same directory.

So what I should get is a **404 Page Not Found** message when I go to a custom URL such as `http://localhost/codeigniter/pages/about` which does not exist yet.

But the problem is, the browser shows me **Object not found!** rather than that.

So what is wrong with this, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how CI works. For starters, `pages/about` does not exist. The regular URI scheme is `Controller`/`method` so you'd need to point to `pages/view`

Going in a little deeper, CI already has an error handler (the pre-made templates which you can change are located in `/views/error` and you can make different error pages depending on the error type

Comment: In other words, point the browser to _http://localhost/codeigniter/pages/about_ to conduct a valid test.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL

`http://localhost/codeigniter/pages/about`

the above URL is not correct, use this instead of above

`http://localhost/codeigniter/pages/view/about`

URL format

`protocol://domain/class/method/var1/var2/...`

`Protocol = http://`

`Domain =  localhost/codeigniter (In localhost)`

`Class = pages`

`Method = view`

`Var1 = about`

`var2 = '' (if any)`